# Is there a way of determining if an element of a list matches the element of another list (of the same index)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am currently doing a data analysis course based on excel, but I want to complete the exercises on Python to increase my proficiency. I have an excel sheet of data on whether or not there was snow cover on each day (1=snow, 0= no snow). So I decided to read this excel file and append each of these numbers to a list to make it easier to work with. Though I can't seem to figure out how to do the next step. I need to iterate through the list starting from the first element; if the element = 1 and the succeeding element also = 1, I want this to append 'T' to a new list (and 'F' in any other case).

**Example:** 
*list = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]*

This would append 'T' as the first element in the new list as the first two elements are = 1. The 2nd and 3rd elements are 1 and 0, therefore should append 'F' to the list. This should continue until the end. Last two elements = 1 so should append 'T.'

Would anyone have any clue on how to do so? This is my attempt but it only seems to return 'F' for every case:

```
def trans1(snow):
cover1 = []
snow1 = snow
snow2 = snow[1:]
for num1 in snow1:
    for num2 in snow2:
        if num1 == 1 and num2 ==1:
            trans01.append("T")
        else:
            trans01.append("F")
return cover1
```

Cheers!

Comment: Try merging on index and the relevant column, should work if I understand correctly

Comment: You can `zip` the original and the shifted list together and check each tuple in _one_ for-loop (or list comprehension) for desired state to fill a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip()` the list with itself at an offset and the compare in a list comprehension with something like:

```
l = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

res = ['T' if a == b else 'F' for a, b in zip(l, l[1:])]
# res -> ['T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T']
```

If you are just interested in the boolean values instead of strings, it's simpler still:

```
[a == b for a, b in zip(l, l[1:])]
# [True, False, False, False, False, True]
```

[edit based on comment]

If you only want to test for both `1`s, you can change the test to use `and` rather than `==`. For example:

```
l = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] 
res = ['T' if a and b else 'F' for a, b in zip(l, l[1:])]
# res -> ['F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F']
```

will give all `F`s for input of all zeros.

Comment: I actually like this solution more than mine, but `zip` does add a higher level of (imo) unnecessary complexity. Good stuff though +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the list comprehension makes it much easier! Solved my problem :)

Comment: This doesn’t match the desired behavior specified in the OP in the case of successive zeros: “if the element = 1 and the succeeding element also = 1, I want this to append 'T' to a new list (**and 'F' in any other case**).”  Then again, it was just accepted as the answer, so maybe I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasM, I think you're correct. I added an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with list comprehension as follow:

```py
["T" if l[i] == l[i+1] else "F" for i in range(len(l)-1)]
```

```
l = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
o = ["T" if l[i] == l[i+1] else "F" for i in range(len(l)-1)]

print(o) #> ['T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T']
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

`["T" if l[i] == l[i+1] else "F" for i in range(len(l)-1)]`

a longer but more understandable approach:

```
ans = []
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i]==l[i+1]:
        ans.append("T")
    else:
        ans.append("F")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that uses one pass through your list. It may be less elegant than one line solution with zip method, but more understandable:

```
def trans1(snow):
    cover1 = []
    num_prev=snow[0]
    for num_next in snow[1:]:
        if num_next+num_prev==2:
            cover1.append('T')
        else:
            cover1.append('F')
        num_prev=num_next

    return cover1
```

So, it has an additional variable `num_prev` that stores a "previous" number. After iterating through the succeeding number, we append a corresponding letter to the cover1 list. At the end of the loop we update the previous number.